# Compiled against a different Node.js version using NODE_MODULE_VERSION

Tags: node.js, electron, robotjs

Nodejs version: v12.22.11

Electron version: ^11.1.0

RobotJS version: ^0.6.0

The following error message will be prompted when executing the project.

```
App threw an error during load
Error: The module '\\?\\node_modules\robotjs\build\Release\robotjs.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 72. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 85. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1812)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1203:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1812)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:992:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12738)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (\node_modules\robotjs\index.js:1:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1152:30)
```

I have tried execute `npm rebuild` and `npm install`. But this doesn't solve my problem.

## 20221029-Updated


This is my whole package.json

```
{
  "name": "robotjs-proj",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps && node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild --module-dir .",
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "electron": "^11.1.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
    "mathjs": "^8.1.0",
    "robotjs": "^0.6.0",
    "robotjs-node12": "^0.5.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.7",
    "electron-rebuild": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

insert postinstall script to your package.json

```
...
"start": .......,
"preinstall": .....,
"postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps && node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild --module-dir .",
"dist": ....,
...
```

Comment: Can you share the whole package.json for me? When I execute this script, it prompts an error below. `Error: Cannot find module 'fs/promises' `
`node_modules\builder-util\out\fs.js `
`node_modules\electron-builder\out\cli\cli.js `

Comment: Can you check this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68085375/cannot-find-module-fs-promises-electron-js